# Viewing C# tag then changing sorting drops the # symbol

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Steps to reproduce:

1. [View results for C# tag](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c%23)

   > [image]
2. Change sorting to "date posted"
3. You will now see that your search criteria is for C, not C#.

   > [image]

Comment: Reproduced. Again, I'm confused by the downvote, but w/e.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? I cannot repro on Chrome 30.

Comment: I'm on chrome 30 as well

Comment: Ah. I got it. It doesn't do that when you "search" for C#. You have to use the tags link.

Comment: Correct, only happens when browsing via tag

Comment: @Juice shameless bump... is this scheduled for a fix? :) (I know you can't fix it yourself yet but you can nudge those who can better than us mortals)

Comment: 100 bounty? I'll give it another shot.

Comment: @NickLarsen Roberta was faster and will get the hard earned 100 as soon as I can grant it... fix confirmed so can you please tag this as status-completed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm Roberta's mentor!

Comment: @NickLarsen then you're a great mentor, she squashed that bug like... well, like a bug! :D

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for the report. This issue has now been fixed.

It looks like there's a problem with `Url.AbsolutePath`, which was trimming `'c%23'` into `'c'`.

[image]

Changing it to `Url.RawUrl` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, can you please mention you work for Stack Exchange in your profile though? And you can ask for a diamond here so you can tag such questions [meta-tag:status-completed] after you fix. :-)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard just mentioned it in my profile. Diamond is on its way :) thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `#` was encoded? I'm not observing this behaviour when it's encoded ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/UjdsKcu.png)), while I do see this behaviour when it's not encoded ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/NjL3TGk.png)).

Comment: @Stijn Yep! It indeed works locally, might be an IIS x IIS Express issue.

Comment: @rla4 looks like the reason is Uri.AbsolutePath does not include query portion of the URL and `#` is considered query portion. Anyway, congrats on your shiny new diamond!

Comment: Any chance this fix caused [a new bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224978/152859)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It doesn't really look like, but it's possible :) We're looking at it right now.

Comment: Cheers, glad to hear! :-)