# Bug - StackOverflows Careers C# --> C

Tags: bug, jobs

Issue: Mean to search for keyword: C# actual search ends up being C

Steps to reproduce:

1. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/
2. Click on C# listed next to *keywords*
3. Sort by: Date Posted
4. Realize you are now looking at results for C instead of C#

Note: this is not reproducible if you go through the normal search, only via the keyword click

Comment: this was reported once before, let me find it...! Here it is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203517/viewing-c-tag-then-changing-sorting-drops-the-symbol

Comment: @Jehof - Ah I see, it wasn't in the question so my search didn't hit it direct. But hey, it's still not fixed ;-)

Comment: Usually the careers developers are responsive but for some reason they ignore any bumps in there. Oh well.