# Sorting jobs on careers is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, sorting

The sorting of jobs seems to be broken on [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). It doesn´t matter which sort option I choose, the jobs are always sorted by "Date posted".

As an example when I select sort by "Job title" it gets reset to "Date posted".

The URLs are

"Date posted"-> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=

"Job title"->http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=&sort=t

"Company name"->http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=&sort=c

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)
2. Click Search-Button without entering any search terms
3. Change **sort by** to "Job title" -> result is that **sort by** gets reset to "Date posted"

Comment: Working fine where there is a search term: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=C%23&sort=t :)

Comment: I suspect [this fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224401/152859) might have introduced this bug..

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok interesting. I clicked directly on search-Button,without specifying search terms, on the home page of careers and then changed the filter what results in the described behavior.

Comment: Sure, not doubting there is a bug, just adding some extra details that might help the dev team to debug this. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think the problem is the Search-Button on the Homepage cause it appends this `?searchTerm=&location=`, while the Search-Button on the other pages do not.

Comment: It's working that way because you didn't specify any search terms. If you were to search by any criteria, it would sort correctly. Still a bug but a minor one. I'll see what we can do.

Comment: Confirmed, we're working on a fix.

Comment: @Juice yes of course, but i have not build up the query string on my own. This was done by Careers clicking the search-button on home page. I will update my question accordingly

Comment: @Jehof I understand. What I mean is you performed a search without filling out the what or the where search fields. That's what is causing the bug. Had you put anything in either field, the sorting would be working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now fixed this - there was a bug where the default sort order was being set, which was causing the sort order to be overridden in some circumstances.

Comment: Nice! One minor thing, can the page be reset to 1 when I change the "sort by" filter?

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, done!

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch! :-)