# Tag encoding breaks when redirecting after successful login

Tags: bug, jobs

Here is a little bug I found, this is the step I followed :

- From SO, click the ad link to look for a job in Careers suggesting the 'C#' tag
- View the job list in Careers, with 'C#' written in the keyword field
- Click on 'create account' because you don't have one yet, and create it with your SE account
- Once Carrers is allowed to access your information, you are redirected to the job list you were looking previously, BUT : **the '#' is gone, new keyword field value is only 'c'**

  EDIT : Finally this thread is not duplicated with [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203517/viewing-c-tag-then-changing-sorting-drops-the-symbol) as the issue explained there is supposed to be fixed since 2014, and I had the bug I explained today. I think my issue is slightly different, as my bug is not related with table sorting.

Comment: Edited title to be more technically accurate.